# Writing ruby web-service. What architecture should I use? Rack, Rails-engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, rack

I need to write web-service that will get files over http and convert them. This service in future might be included in rails application. I wonder what I need to use for that? 
Mount as Rack-middleware? Sinatra app? Write Rails-engine? Simple ruby script with networking? Anything else?
Thanks

Comment: It's really hard to say without knowing what files you need to download, what format they are in, and what format you need to convert them into.

Comment: Why so? I thought that's irrelevant. It needs to be pdf-png conversion

Comment: Sinatra is really good for webservice because it's not bloated like rails.

Answer (score 0):

If you may eventually incorporate it in a rails app, then I would use rails to get the service up and running.  The framework provided by rails makes creating web services very easy (sometimes with as little as a line or two of code).